# Vertex with minimal distance to n other vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a directed, weighted, cyclic graph, and minimal path distance between vertices given by m(x,y), find the vertex v that minimises m(a,v) + m(b,v) + m(c,v) + ... for n vertices a, b, c...

For example if the graph was undirected and we wanted the vertex v with minimal paths to vertices a and b, v would just be the vertex in the centre of the minimal path from a to b.

I can imagine an approach involving depth traversal etc, but wanted to ask what SO would suggest - Thanks hope this was clear.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that m is a matrix? If this is the case you would just need to find the row with the minimal sum of entries (a, b, c, ..). I am pretty sure that in the general case (directed graph) with more than two query vertices there is no more efficient solution. If you want to perform many queries on the same graph then there might be some way to preprocess the data.

Comment: I meant in general m as some function that returns the shortest distance between the 2 vertices (ie by performing dijkstra's), but ok interesting

Answer (score 0):

Now that I am thinking a bit more about it, you should probably look at [Bidirectional Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search).

The basic idea would be to start a Dijkstra from each of your query nodes (a, b, c, ...) at the same time. The first vertex that is found by all of them is your result vertex.

You can implement this by putting all (unvisited vertex, distance, query vertex)triplets you encounter in one priority queue (sorted by distance) and process it similar to Dijkstra. You will need to label the the vertices you have seen with the query node from which you reached them. When a vertex is labeled with all query vertices then this is your result (let's call it median vertex).

Comment: Thanks I'll do some more research in this direction